# curl stops working when used in combination with xargs

Tags: curl, xargs

I need to check a list of domains in parallel. So I was planning on using `curl` and `xargs`.

This is `check.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
domain=${1?Pass the domain as a parameter}
curl -o /dev/null --silent --write-out "http://$domain/,%{http_code},%{redirect_url}\n" "http://$domain/"
```

Now, when used a single time it works:

```
$ ./check.sh example.com
http://example.com,200,
```

If instead I use it in combination with `xargs`, `curl` does not work properly and the output looks broken:

```
$ cat domains.txt | xargs -L1 -P2 ./check.sh
,000,//example.com
,000,//example.org
```

This is the test file I'm using (`domains.txt`):

```
example.com
example.org
```

This happens also without `-P2`, so it must be related to the way lines are passed to the script. I also added an `echo "$domain"` in it, but everything looks ok.

Comment: Does your `domains.txt` file have DOS-style CRLF line endings?

Comment: @steeldriver Damn, this was exactly the reason. Please convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it! Thanks a lot!